# c# Save file directory

Tags: c#, directory, save

I want a user to pick a directory to save image files too.  I'm new to c#, I've got the image thing working with OpenFileDialog, how would I do the directory thing.

Basically, I want it to look like:

> Save Directory:  C:\PATH....

Maybe a FolderBrowserDialog or OpenDirectoryDialog?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Could you be more specific than "image thing" and "directory thing?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `FolderBrowserDialog` to select a folder, or use the `SaveFileDialog` to pick an individual file for saving.

Here is a codeplex.com example of using `FolderBrowserDialog`:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/csFolderBrowseDialogEx.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use a FolderBrowserDialog. Here's an example:

```
FolderBrowserDialog brwsr = new FolderBrowserDialog();

//Check to see if the user clicked the cancel button
if (brwsr.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
    return;
else
{
    newDirectoryPath = brwsr.SelectedPath;
    //Do whatever with the new path
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you want the [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog(v=VS.85).aspx).